# How do I create a public action, but keep the invoke private?

Tags: c#, events, action

Let say I have an action like this:

```
public Action OnSomeAction;
```

I would like to be able to subscribe to this action from outside of the class, but not be able to invoke it:

```
OnSomeAction.Invoke();
```

Is there a way to do this **without** making the action private and creating methods for subscribing and unsubscribing like this:

```
private Action _someAction;

public void Subscribe(Action listener)
{
    _someAction += listener;
}

public void Unsubscribe(Action listener)
{
    _someAction -= listener;
}

private void Invoke()
{
    _someAction.Invoke();
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for `event`?

Comment: That was it, cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for [event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/event)?

```
public class MyClass {
  // Let firing event be private 
  private void onMyAction() {
    Action action = MyAction;

    if (action != null)
      action();
  }

  public void FireDemo() {
    onMyAction();
  }

  //TODO: I've put Action, but, probably, EventHandler will be a better choice
  // while event itself (subscribe / unsubscribe) being public
  public event Action MyAction;
}
```

**Demo:**

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

var first = () => {Console.WriteLine("I'm the first")};
var second = () => {Console.WriteLine("I'm the second")};
var none = () => {Console.WriteLine("I should not fire")};

myClass.MyAction += first;
myClass.MyAction += second;
myClass.MyAction += none;

// Unsubsribe
myClass.MyAction -= none;

// Direct attempt will NOT compile:
// myClass.MyAction();

myClass.FireDemo();
```

Comment: You can use the pattern `MyAction?.Invoke();` instead. This assigns the delegate to a hidden temp, making this safe in multithreading.

Comment: @Olivier Jacot-Descombes: you are quite right, thank you! `MyAction?.Invoke();` is the most compact and readable implementation and that's why is the standard one; however, my goal, as I saw it, was to provide the simplest code; to show what `event` and `action` are, that's why I put it wordy.

Comment: So what is stopping me from doing `myClass.MyAction = () => { }`? Wouldn't that assignment just wipe out previous subscriptions?

Comment: @benderto: note that `MyAction` is an *event* (not *field* or *property*), and in case of *event* all you can do is to `Add` or `Remove`, but *not assign* (note long form of event declaration: `public event Action MyAction {add {...} remove {...}}`). So `myClass.MyAction = () => { }` code *will not compile*.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Thank you for response, I totally overlooked the `event` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Although this looks a lot like events. You can achieve it using `Action` too. Consider following code which is almost same as you suggested:

```
private List<Action> _someActionList = new List<Action>();

public void Subscribe(Action listener)
{
    _someActionList.Add(listener);
}

public void Unsubscribe(Action listener)
{
    _someActionList.Remove(listener);
}

private void Invoke()
{
    foreach(action in _someActionList)
    {
        action();
    }
}
```

I hope this is exactly what you want to do. If not then please elaborate further.

Comment: I was looking for a cleaner way of doing this, that didn't include extra methods and I didn't realize events did exactly what I wanted.

This is what I ended up with:

`public delegate void SomeEvent();`
`public event SomeEvent OnSomeEvent;`